# Losing vertical alignment when using minipage inside tabular

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, enumerate, minipage

I am using a minipage and an enumerate inside a tabular. However, when I do that, the vertical alignment of the "hello" part in the code is lost.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{2cm} | >{\arraybackslash} m{\textwidth} }
    \textit{Hello} & One \newline
    Two \newline
    \textit{{Three}}
    
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
        \begin{itemize}[left=2mm, topsep=0pt, label={-}, noitemsep, nosep, partopsep=0pt, after=\strut]
            \item \small Four
            \item \small Five
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage} \\
\end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

And here is the output

[image: Not vertically aligned]

Does anyone know how to make it vertically aligned? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Remark: With `m{2cm}` and `m{\textwidth}`, it's certain that your tabular will be too wide.

Comment: Thank you! I already changed it to `m{2cm}` and `m{11cm}`.

Comment: Do you expect *Hello* to be aligned with *Three*? Or do you want *Hello* to be vertically centered in its cell (it's not exactly the same thing)?

Comment: I expect _Hello_ to be vertically centered in its cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

- remove minipage around list
- by help of `etoolbox` define list style in preamble
- to list style add `minipage`, see MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{% <---
    \setlist[itemize]{nosep=0pt,
                     leftmargin=1.5em,
                     label=--,
                     after=\end{minipage},                   
                     before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}}
                     }

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm} | m{5cm} }
\textit{Hello}  &   One \newline
                    Two \newline
                    \textit{Three}
                    \begin{itemize}\small 
                \item   Four
                \item   Five
                    \end{itemize}   \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using Overleaf editor, everything (the code) appears red in the main document when adding your code. Is there a way of fixing it?

Comment: My MWE as is, work in Overleaf. Tested. However I haven't any clue, how you include proposed solution in your document, how your document is structured etc. Sory, due to lack of information, I can't help you,

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. In that environment, which is similar to the classical `{tabular}` (of the package `array`), there is a command `\Block`. In your case, you can put `Hello` in a mono-cell `\Block`: that allows the use of the key `v-center` for that `\Block`. With that key, the content of the block is mathematically centered in the cell (by using PGF computations).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{2cm} | >{\arraybackslash} m{11cm} }[hvlines]
    \Block[v-center]{}{\textit{Hello}} & One \newline
    Two \newline
    \textit{{Three}}

\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
        \begin{itemize}[left=2mm, topsep=0pt, label={-}, noitemsep, nosep, partopsep=0pt, after=\strut]
            \item \small Four
            \item \small Five
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage} \\
\end{NiceTabular} 

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations, because of the PGF/Tikz nodes used by `nicematrix` under the hood.

[image: Output of the above code]